# How to get environment variable in Jenkins email notification?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins job configuration I have written a bat script in the command window of build section. In one of the script commands I set an environment variable as a system environment variable in the server machine as so:

`setx Analysis_URL "http://analysis_url/analysis/%analysis_id%.html`

My task now is to get this environment variable value back to Jenkins and include it in my post build notification email content. Is there a simple way to do it ?

In my research I have come across the plugin envInject but I think it is used for setting environment variables, is that right ?

UPDATE 1 :

It turned out that the variable could be accessed by a simple $Analysis_URL in the email content, however, that raised another issue as my environment variable changes its value after each job build, but as Jenkins only takes a copy of the system environment variables I keep getting the same variable value after each build in my email content, it only changes after restarting Jenkins. Is there a way to get the updated system environment variables to Jenkins ?

UPDATE 2 :

EnvInject plugin did the job I wanted. These are the steps that I performed:

1. Build step "batch command window": added command :

`echo ANALYSIS_URL=$ANALYSIS_URL > my.properties`

2. Build step "Inject environment variables": in field "Properies File Path"

`$WORKSPACE/my.properties`

3. Post-Build Actions: "Editable Email Notification", Field "Default Content":

Current analysis url: `$ANALYSIS_URL`

Comment: this method works, there is a typo, $WORDKSPACE/my.properties should be $WORKSPACE/my.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `env.Analysis_URL` to access to your environment variable ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answer, I am new to Jenkins. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not even sure if this works, but for example, you can access to your PATH variable with the env.PATH. ex : env.PATH = "C:\\test" and an other command echo "${env.PATH}". So, if this works, you could use : ${env.Analysis_URL} (value of)  in the post section.

Comment: I have marked your suggestion as answer as it gave me some hints to solve my issue.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer more? Or @sadrab can you explain what you did to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Printing Variables in Post Build Email:

1. Add this to build: execute shell section:

```
echo count=$count > count.txt
echo distinctcount=$distinctcount > distinctcount.txt
```

[image: execute shell section]

2. Add this to Inject Environmental Variables section under "Properties File Path":

```
${WORKSPACE}/count.txt
```

[image: Properties File Path]
and do the same also for the second file `${WORKSPACE}/distinctcount.txt` (as I have two variables)

Note 1: `${WORKSPACE}` is pwd for jenkins and lists the location)

Note 2: You can actually put both variables in just one file by using `echo distinctcount=$distinctcount >> count.txt`

3. Call the variable in the "default content" section of "editable email notification":

```
Count total:$count Distinct Count: $distinctcount
```

[image: editable email notification]

**NOTE**
Be sure you have email setup as "always" under "advanced settings" at the bottom of the email settings, otherwise it only emails upon first success or any failure:

[image: advanced settings]
[image: email setup as "always"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables and global variables inside script with `sh`. For example:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    APP_VERSION = "1.2.1"
  }
  post {
    success {
      script {
        sh "sed -i 's#%BUILD_URL#$BUILD_URL#g' .jenkins/email.html"
        sh "sed -i 's#%APP_VERSION#${APP_VERSION}#g' .jenkins/email.html"
        emailext attachLog: true, mimeType: 'text/html', body: '${FILE, path=".jenkins/email.html"}', subject: '[$BUILD_STATUS] $PROJECT_NAME', to: 'youremail@mail.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the secret is here:

- `'` single quote parses global variables like `$BUILD_STATUS $BUILD_URL` ...
- `"` double quote parses env variables like `${APP_VERSION}`

So, you can use:

```
subject: '$BUILD_STATUS'
```

or

```
subject: "${APP_VERSION}"
```

## Final solution

Transform all global variables you need to environment variables:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    APP_VERSION = "1.2.1"
  }
  post {
    success {
      script {
        BUILD_STATUS = '$BUILD_STATUS'
        PROJECT_NAME = '$PROJECT_NAME'
        sh "sed -i 's#%BUILD_URL#$BUILD_URL#g' .jenkins/email.html"
        sh "sed -i 's#%APP_VERSION#${APP_VERSION}#g' .jenkins/email.html"
        emailext attachLog: true, mimeType: 'text/html', body: '${FILE, path=".jenkins/email.html"}', subject: "${BUILD_STATUS} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_VERSION}", to: 'youremail@mail.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use: **${yourDefinedVriableName}**